# How can I get legacy documentation for boto3?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto3

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/develop/,http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, all link to the same version (1.4.7). I'm looking for documentation for older versions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you seeking older documentation? Do you want the documentation for `boto` (v2) instead of `boto3`? If so, it is at boto.readthedocs.io

Comment: my apologies, earlier releases of boto3. I think Mark B has the best answer to date. I was just hoping for something simpler. (Although in the grander scheme of things, I suppose it took longer to write the post than it would have to have generated the docs!)

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout the version of Boto3 [from GitHub](https://github.com/boto/boto3) that you want to view the docs for. Then run the Makefile in the `/docs` folder to generate the docs for that version.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. I was hoping that the docs were maintained elsewhere for ease of access. Appreciate it!